# I am new to sharepoint and need to take over our companies sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am a site owner but not admin - how do I take over as Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to access Central Administration, and set yourself as a Farm Administrator. Generally, on your server you can get there by going to Start > Administrative Tools > SharePoint Central Administration.

For more information regarding how to get to the area to add yourself, once you connect to Central Administration, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288153(v=office.12).

Answer (score 0):

While there are a few witty remarks I would like to make they probably won't help you.  :(

Somebody with access will need to grant you "Farm Administrator" permissions within Central Administration.